# MinorFS: Installation

Tags: database, perl, ubuntu, cloud, fuse

Hi i want to install MinorFS 0.3.5 to my computer. My Ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS. But i had some problems while installing the program.

Firstly i installed all fuse modules and gcc and run the script install.pl.

The program is designed for Ubuntu 8. As a result it wants to install fuse module to start the script install.pl.

But there is not a loadable fuse module for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I research about it and i see that, for the latest version of Ubuntu, the kernel is configured to include FUSE instead of compiling it as a module. So, i modified the perl code in install.pl and 
install the script.(I install fuseiso with command apt-get install fuseiso just in case.)

Everyting is great for the moment. But for the next step, i run the command on terminal "/etc/init.d/minorfs start ".
And i get this error : " The path specified in /var/minorfs/viewfs.startcap is not a valid base dir for minorviewfs
"
This command runs the minorcapfs and minorviewfs i guess.Minorcapfs run succesfully but for minorviewfs i got this error.

The code which gives the Error writen below:(in minorviewfs file)

```
unless (-d $basepath) {
    print STDERR "The path specified in $VARDIR/viewfs.startcap is not a valid base dir for minorviewfs\n";
    exit 1;
}
```

Then for test, i print my " $basepath " and it's : /mnt/minorfs/cap/61ce0488ac06eba530e178a0d1716ec576b47f71

I couldn't solve this error.

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: `-d` tests existence of a directory. So this means: `$basepath` is not a directory. There's 4 reasons why that might be: a) you forgot to `chomp $basepath` when you read it from somewhere else. b) It doesn't exist. c) It does exist, but it's not a directory. d) It exists, and is a directory but the user running the script doesn't have the right permissions.

Comment: a) the code has chomp $basepath;


As I said when i print the $basepath i get: /mnt/minorfs/cap/61ce0488ac06eba530e178a0d1716ec576b47f71


Then on terminal; ls /mnt/minorfs/cap 
Nothing..

Comment: try `ls -ld /mnt/minorfs/cap/61ce0488ac06eba530e178a0d1716ec576b47f71` - does that exist? Because that's literally what your script is testing.

Comment: It doesn't exist :(
i get "
ls: cannot access /mnt/minorfs/cap/61ce0488ac06eba530e178a0d1716ec576b47f71: No such file or directory "

Comment: Any suggestion?! I stucked :(

Comment: That's why your script isn't working  - no such file or directory, means your directory doesn't exist. I don't know how or why, because you've only posted the snippet of script that tests whether it exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with manually making a directory with the mkdir command. Now the script work. But now I have a different problem. The output is ;
 Starting MinorFs filesystems minorcapfs going into background, consult syslog for information      minorviewfs going into background, consult syslog for information.

Then when i run the command  ls -la /mnt/minorfs/priv

i should get a links to the folders. But I have nothing.
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jan  1  1970 .
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1  1970 home -> 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1  1970 tmp ->

So i looked the system log file  with gedit /var/log/syslog and i see that Error;

Sep  1 13:51:37 burak-UX31A minorcapfs[3581]: Problem in Fuse::main at /usr/local/bin/minorcapfs line 340
Sep  1 13:51:37 burak-UX31A minorcapfs[3581]: user: 0 1001 ; group 104 104 104 104 at /usr/local/bin/minorcapfs line 341
Sep  1 13:51:37 burak-UX31A minorcapfs[3581]: Probably a problem accesing /dev/fuse at /usr/local/bin/minorcapfs line 342
Sep  1 13:52:01 burak-UX31A minorviewfs[3584]: Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at /usr/lib/perl5/Fuse.pm line 147,  line 26.

And this the MinorCapfs code ; http://codepad.org/nUUJ3b5m

How to get rid of this problems? Thank you.